# Storing date as integer (numeric), what are the advantages

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date-format

### **Question 1**

I am working with a system where date is stored as integer (actual numeric(8,0)) and I have noticed that other systems also store date as int such as [cisco in this thread](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic803419-338-1.aspx). Example

```
20120101  -- 01 Jan 2012
```

Is there any advantage of keeping numeric date system and not using SQL Datetime?

### **Question 2**

Now I am trying to loop through numeric date to find customers between two dates. If the `start` and `enddate` encompass two months, I get thousands of records instead of just 60. Example:

```
create table #temp1(day int,capacity int) /* just a temp table */

declare @start int 
declare @end int

set @start=20111201
set @end = 20120131

while (@start <= @end) 
Begin
    insert into #temp1  /* I am storing things in #temp table so data looks pretty */
    exec usp_GetDailyCap @date1= @start

    set @start = @start + 1;    
end

select * from #temp1
```

This pulls 8931 records instead of 60. Is there a better way to improve the logic above so I pull only valid dates? I tried IsDate and sub-queries but that did not quite work in an efficient way.

Comment: If you're running SQL Server 2008 or higher, you can actually just use the data type Date.  It's a bit smaller and doesn't force you to include time, but almost all of SQL's datetime functions still work for it.

Comment: I only see disadvantages in this approach no advantage whatsoever

Answer (score 12):

To answer your first question, I would recommend using the `DATETIME` data type within SQL Server.  Not necessarily for performance reasons, but to leverage the RDBMS-specific functionality.  For instance, you would have to re-invent a lot of logic just to do basic date math (think `DATEDIFF()`, `DATEADD()`, `DATEPART()` and many other functions.  They are obviously tailored to the `DATETIME` data type and are easy to work with).

As for your second question, **you are running into the exact problem that the first question (and my answer) is geared towards**.  *You* are looking at 20111201 and 20120131 as dates, and your brain is telling you that should be a difference of 60 days.  Well, you're looping through based off of the delta...which is:

`20120131 - 20111201 = 8930` *(with the inclusive loop it'll be 8931)*

In other words, your `WHILE` loop is executing 8931 times.  This is happening because those are integer values and your loop will not jump from 20111231 straight to 20120101.

You integers aren't going to take into account the cap of years and months (i.e. your **Question 2** problem).

Comment: Well that is exactly my question. For numeric dates, loops can go into thousands, not just 30 days or 29 days. But bear in mind that I am working with a **professional system**. And even cisco uses it as it seems.

Comment: Besides performance and functionality, there's also integrity. With integers as dates, the db would allow `20121301` and `20120230` and even `20129999` as a date.

Comment: @Jackofall Cisco doesn't have the platform of an RDBMS behind it.  They wrote their own logic.  Why *wouldn't* they just use integers.  From the ground up, that is probably the easiest way for low-level software.  But we're talking about apples and oranges here.

Comment: @Shark, the software I am dealing with is called Nexant. The database is highly professionally written (no novice here), Relationship, Foreign keys, large number of table, proper encoding of field names. But I get your point and I agree with you, it looses data integrity to talk the least. Still why a professional system would use numeric date?

Comment: @Jackofall: There is a great difference between storing dates as integers (and having gaps) and storing datetimes/timestamps as integers - or even dates as integers, like VB/Excel does.

Comment: Your link suggests that Cisco is storing Unix timestamps (or some variant).

Comment: There are many (if not most) professionally designed databases that use bad techniques. I have worked with many COTS products and not seen any that were well-deisgned from a database perspective.

Comment: @HLGEM - that's normally due to legacy issues and the difficulty of refactoring systems designed in the <insert_decade_of_your_choice>, when RDBMSs weren't as sophisticaed as they are now!

Answer (score 6):

1. Ralph Kimball recommends storing dates as integers. He has written a lot, both online articles and books.
2. You can use a calendar table and issue consecutive numbers to your dates, as follows:

   Date Number

   20120229   1234

   20120301   1235

The calendar table has to be generated, but it is a very easy task.

Comment: I'd like to see the case where you filter a query by joining to a date table with the dates stored as numeric and filtering those numeric dates would beat using "where [date] between @startdate and @enddate"

Comment: @DForck42 there is no need for the case you are suggesting: "where [dateAsInt] between 20120229  and 20120329" would return exactly the same rows as "where [date] between '20120229' and '20120329'"

Comment: And what was his reasoning?

Answer (score 5):

**Potential data types and their sizes/limitations:**

- Decimal(8,0): 5 bytes
- Date: 3 bytes, 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31
- Int: 4 bytes

**Pros for numeric data type:**

- They look pretty?

**Cons for numeric data type:**

- Requires custom code for handling date operations
- Requires custom code to manage correct dates (ie, not allowing 20120230 [Feb 30th, 2012])
- Larger data footprint when compared to the Date data type.

Honestly, you're better off using the date data type IMHO.